# Wp-admin uses different php.ini than the theme files

Tags: apache, php.ini

A strange issue with my webhost (which doesn't seem to have an idea either). I tried to increase the upload limit for the wp installation by changing values in the php.ini.

If I check which php.ini -file the site loads with `php_ini_loaded_file()`, the call in wp-admin/upload.php returns "/usr/local/lib/php.ini", but the same function in the wp-content/themes/themefolder/header.php returns "/home/account694/public_html/php.ini"

The host uses a "shared" type of php.ini where all settings in a php.ini-file in the public_html -folder overrides the default ones.

I've checked that it isn't related to my own machine. How can this even be possible?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the hosting company configuration, and the best thing you can do is to contact your hosting company so they can explain the rules they use for loading PHP.ini files.

Comment: They seem to be as confused about it as me :)

Comment: You should change the hosting then. If hosting support is confused about how their own server works is the ckear sign that time has come to change host.